# Oracle: Integer field returning NUMBER

Tags: java, oracle, sqldatatypes

I am creating the following table in oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
 DKEY INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 NOM VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL
)
```

When i try to get the type of the DKEY field using this java code, I get the following result:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = cnx.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsmd = md.getColumns(null, strSchema, strTableName, "%");
while (rsmd != null && rsmd.next()) {
    String strTmp = rsmd.getString("SQL_DATA_TYPE");  // this return 0 for field DKEY
    int intDType = rsmd.getInt("DATA_TYPE");          // this return 3 for field DKEY
    String strFType = rsmd.getString("TYPE_NAME")     // this return NUMBER for field DKEY
}
```

Why do i get NUMBER instead of INTEGER?

Comment: Did you read the chapter in the Oracle manual that describes the available datatypes? Because that does answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can specify `INTEGER` as the data type in the SQL statement, Oracle will use `NUMBER(38)` in its implementation.

See Oracle data types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289) and [this](http://psoug.org/definition/INTEGER.htm) article.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one more question : why rsmd.getString("COLUMN_SIZE") returns 0 not 38? is there another methode to get the size? i tried getPrecision but also it returned 0

Comment: If you read the javadoc for getPrecision, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getPrecision(int), it says _0 is returned for data types where the column size is not applicable_. I don't know any other way. Use SQL to get table metadata with a DESCRIBE statement or whatever Oracle uses.

Comment: getPrecision is going to return 0 if you specify Integer, Number, or Number(*,n) where n is >= 0. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/be559/2

Answer (score 0):

I think the table column DKEY property type is NUMBER

But try

```
while (rsmd != null && rsmd.next()) {
    String strTmp = rsmd.getString("SQL_DATA_TYPE");  // this return 0 for field DKEY
    int intDType = Integer.parseInt(rsmd.getLong("DATA_TYPE"));          // this return 3 for field DKEY
    String strFType = rsmd.getString("TYPE_NAME")     // this return NUMBER for field DKEY
}
```